# Adding axis labels to multcompview constrast plots

Tags: r

I have been using package multcompview to be able to visually display the significant differences among groups based on anova and HSD tukey tests:

```
Group=c("G1","G1","G1","G1","G2","G2","G2","G2","G3","G3","G3","G3")
set.seed(0)
Vals=c(runif(4),runif(4)+0.7,runif(4)-0.7)
data=data.frame(Group)
data=cbind(data, Vals)  
library(multcompView)
xzx <-multcompBoxplot(Vals~Group,data=data,sortFn=median,  decreasing=FALSE,    
                  horizontal=FALSE,
                  plotList=list(
                    boxplot=list(fig=c(0,  1,  0,  1),  las=3,
                                 cex.axis=1.5),                      
                    multcompLetters=list(
                      fig=c(0.87,  0.97,  0.115,  0.923), #0.1108, 0.9432 Top of     
                      #page 18 manual for very convoluted explanation (c(y bottom, y top,x L, x R))
                      type='Letters') ) )
```

[image]

Here is one exampel of one of my actual graphs:
[image]
The approach (which I found after posting a related question in SO) works really well, but I have not found a way to be able to add a y axis label (I need to label the Y variable "ranked vulnerabity"). The multcomp function does not seem to take in an ylab argument.
It is frustrating to have these overall good looking contrast graphs without basic axis label information…
Do you know of a solution/ workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've also tried this nice, but not self-explaining package.
I found out that when you want to label the axis or the main title you have to launch title() after multcompBoxplot().
For example:

```
title(ylab = 'Response', main = 'Title')
```

Answer (score 1):

After getting no responses from anyone else at SO and looking around for various solutions of varying complexity, I have found one that works well and is very simple (using mtext):

```
Group=c("G1","G1","G1","G1","G2","G2","G2","G2","G3","G3","G3","G3")
set.seed(0)
Vals=c(runif(4),runif(4)+0.7,runif(4)-0.7)
data=data.frame(Group)
data=cbind(data, Vals)  
library(multcompView)
xzx <-multcompBoxplot(Vals~Group,data=data,sortFn=median,  decreasing=FALSE,    
                      horizontal=FALSE,
                      plotList=list(
                        boxplot=list(fig=c(0,  1,  0,  1),  las=3,
                                     cex.axis=1.5),                      
                        multcompLetters=list(
                          fig=c(0.87,  0.97,  0.115,  0.923), #0.1108, 0.9432 Top of     
                          #page 18 manual for very convoluted explanation (c(y bottom, y top,x L, x R))
                      type='Letters') ) )
mtext(side = 2, "Response", line = 2.3, cex=1.5)
```

[image]